# Qt reimplement function

Tags: c++, qt

I need to subclass qt class and reimplement the virtual function. 
Say that i have the `QLCDNumber` class and I want to reimplement the function that set the position of the number when resize the LCD number screen, how to achieve that?

I read that by inhert a class from `QLCDNumber` and reimplement the function,
but where to get that function code so that I can edit what needed in that function? I read the documentation but it explains the function uses and not show its code. Example image:
[image: Example image]

I mentioned the `QLCDNumber` class as example, I need to know the prosses of reimplemnt a virtual Qt class function.

Comment: QLCDNumber is kinda bad example, I don't think it is possible to do what you want with it. So to be clear, you want help with overriding the virtual protected functions of Qt classes, [for example these](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#protected-functions)?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem you can use this type of approach where you can create an object which inherits **QWidget** and implement the paintEvent() of the class like this:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget();
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe);
signals:
public slots:
};
```

and in the paintEvent()

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{
    QPainter *painter = new QPainter(this);
    painter->begin(this);
    // draw what you want here using painter
    // and consider your different layouts
    painter->end();
}
```

Comment: but if i do this method then it will need to do all function in QLCDNumber again, i thought that qt classes function can reimplemented so that if need to change minor thing in class, not the base classes(QWidget) function. thanks for help